# How do I make a post request from a react front-end to a node back-end? Getting 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern, react-fullstack

I'm trying to make a simple website where users can post things to learn the MEAN stack. When I'm handling the POST request, which will be handled and inputed to the MongoDB server through the back-end. React is on port 3000, and the server is on 5000. How do I make the request go from 3000 to 5000? My request works through Postman but not using axios. I added the proxy to the client-side package.json.

I've tried changing the proxy, adding CORS, changing to every single possible route. Nothing works.

Back-end:

```
router.post('/api/req',(req,res)=>{
    const newPost = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description
    })
    newPost.save().then(()=>{
        console.log('Item added to database!')
    });

})
```

Front-end:

```
axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/api/req',
      data: {
        title: this.state.title
      },
      validateStatus: (status) => {
        return true; 
      },
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"  - package.json

I'm expecting the POST request to go through, and for the title to be inputed into the database. Instead, I get the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

The error is coming from localhost:3000/api/req, and it should be proxying port 5000. Also, the actual route is routes/api/req.js.

Comment: I'd expect your req to be `req.body.data.title`, `req.body.data.description`

Comment: I've never seen anyone set a proxy in the package.json? What webserver are you using for development? Proxy in that configuration not the package.json

Comment: If you are serving both the front end and backend from the same box you have to specify the full URL, with the port, that the backend is listening on (just like you're sending requests in Postman).. `axios({ url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/req',  ..... }` - you do not need a proxy to accomplish this. I am currently running the exact same config...

Comment: @MattOestreich wow! It's finally working once I did that. Thanks!

Comment: @MattOestreich although now I'm getting a CORS error.

Comment: You need to add some sort of CORS middleware to your backend/API... [Here is an example of how to do so..](https://gist.github.com/oze4/26cdb8c357e5be3a292cad0806d85ad3) (assuming you're using Express)

Comment: @MattOestreich Yep! Got that too! It's working now :)  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the complete url:

```
axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://example.com:5000/api/req',
      data: {
        title: this.state.title
      },
      validateStatus: (status) => {
        return true; 
      },
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: OP says they are proxying the requests.

Comment: OP does say they are proxying requests, but you don't need to.. Mithun is correct that you need the entire URL - only that he left off the port... `url: 'http://example.com:5000/api/req'` - where `5000` is the port that the API is listening on.

Comment: I've heard that if I'm proxying,  I don't need the full URL.

Comment: You need complete url, by the by have you installed and configured bodyparser to your backend?

Comment: I figured it out. Matt's comment saved me. Although, I'm still getting a CORS error.